# download video link for iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, video

how to create a download video link for iPad/iPhone, I am using something like this

```
<a id="wellcome-video-strem" href="iphone.m4v"><img src="imgButtonDownloadVideo.png" alt="Download Video" /></a>
```

but clicking on this link start to play video file in iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Safari provides no means to save a file to the device's video library.

You might be able to store data using [local storage](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/TicTacToe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010309), but I doubt you will be allowed to store enough data to make saving video feasible (and it would limit access to the saved data to your web site). If you took this approach then you would probably have to resort to generated a `data:` scheme URI in a `<video>` element to play it back.

Answer (score 0):

iPads and iphones support HTML5, so i think you should go for this approach.
Here is a link http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp for HTML5 video tag.

my bad. i misunderstood your post.

There is no way to download a video to your iphone/iPad. You can link your customers to a free download manager on the Appstore to download files.