# How can a web developer let iPhone users download files in 2019?

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, http-headers

I made a site for users to upload and download their content and quickly came complaints from iPhone users that my site is garbage and the downloads don't work for them.

Is there a way for "web developers" to make downloadable content available for iPhone browsers yet?

All the old answers say no, but they are older, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934612/prompt-download-for-safari-and-chrome-on-iphone) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624410/download-video-link-for-ipad-iphone).

Please tell me that Apple allows users to download or crossload content to their device or their cloud storage in the browser, or a workaround that I as the developer can implement.

I can't keep their files on the server. The clients have to offload their content.

The clients haven't appreciated me telling them that it's their phone's fault.

The headers are set for file transfer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 22:07:00 GMT
Server: urmom
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: public
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.mp4"
Content-Length: 60654554
```

Comment: You say they upload and download content.  But then you say you can't keep their files on the server?  Where are they being uploaded?

Comment: **I believe that the older answers are still up-to-date.** I don't thing Apple would remove that restriction as it make it harder to illegally share music (or video). So "download" and "stream" are more or less the same thing except that the UI is different. If you really want to download data to your phone, I think you would have to make a custom application.

Comment: @caden. The problem is that iphone users can't upload or download. I said that the files can't stay on the server because the clients have to retrieve their files and new space has to be cleared up. My only solution so far is to tell them to use an actual computer, but they complain and think it's my fault that Apple is the way it is.

Comment: @Phil. The users need to have future access to their files, independent of the page. I'm not an iphone user. Does Apple really require all these other content sites to have apps in order to push and retrieve data from their device?

Comment: Audio and video files are among the hardest to use outside of Apple provided channels on iPhone. They are not visible as regular files on iOS and even major USB key companies are not able to copy audio file from/to the device. Other file types like PDF are much less restricted.

Comment: @AuntJemima I have an iphone.. And I have an app called Files. I can download to that app and upload from that app...

Comment: @caden311. Thanks I'll tell my clients to use that.